# Airflow webserver not able to access remote worker logs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

i have my airflow docker container running with celery worker nodes, the jobs are getting triggered correctly. However from the `webserver` UI section the it cannot reach the worker for log, showing as

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/airflow/logs/spark-submit/transform/2021-08-07T04:21:58.646836+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://localhost.localdomain:8793/log/spark-submit/transform/2021-08-07T04:21:58.646836+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

trying to diagnose why this happened? does it mean that the webserver is not able to resolve the worker ip address correctly? How can i configure this worker ip mapping somewhere?

I've tried set up the hostname in `airflow.cfg` as

```
hostname_callable = airflow.utils.net.get_host_ip_address
```

but doesn't help.

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Version:

```
airflow==2.1.2
celery[redis]==4.4.2
```

Comment: Are the log files present on the worker nodes?

Comment: From the webserver container can you reach the workers? Does `ping` to worker_nodes IP's work?